# How To Get All Values In HashMap Using globalMap.get()

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following scenario :

```
Map<String, HashSet<String>> B = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

if(!B.containsKey(row5.issue)){
   B.put(row5.issue,new HashSet<String>());
}

B.get(row5.issue).add(row5.name);
globalMap.put("BMap", B);
```

Now, I have the following scripts in another Subjob:

```
"select * from Table  where name in ('" + BMap.values() + "');"
```

The bold portion has problems, anyone can advise? Thanks very much.

Comment: what `BMap.values()` return ?

Comment: I want it returning all the values in the HashMap B which was defined  in the first paragraph scripts. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: it still not clear, you provide an example?

Comment: How is `globalMap` defined? Is it a static `Map<String, Map<String, HashSet<String>>`? If so you should be able to do `WhateverclassGlobalMapIsIn.globalMap.get("BMap").values()`

Comment: The key of hashmap is issue, value of the hashmap is names. Now I want to use all the names in hashmap to query in Mysql. The ideal scenario is that where clause returns all the names stored in the hashmap. Thanks!

Comment: I was implementing this in the Talend, so globalMap is already defined by the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through your `BMap` and build a String based on it's values to query the database with. I am presuming your `HashSet<String>` holds the names in your `HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>`.

```
String sql_statement = "";
for(HashSet<String> names : BMap.values()){
  for(String name : names){
    sql_statement += "'" + name + "',";
  }
}
sql_statement = sql_statement.substring(0, sql_statement.length-1); // to remove the comma at the end
```

And the select statement will look like this:

```
"select * from Table  where name in (" + sql_statement +");"
```

I haven't tested this but it should give you the general idea on how to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed reply, do you know if we can fix this just in the sql scripts, I mean in the where clause?

Comment: Are the SQL scripts seperate from the Java program?

Comment: Yes, Java program was in the first job and sql scripts were in the 2nd job.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "job"?

Comment: Because my program was implemented on Talend platform. Job generally means different modules or workflows, each job runs separately and after the finish of last job running

Comment: OK. I'm not familiar with Talend at all, so I can't really help you there. However, a quick search on google yielded [this](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Passing+a+value+from+a+parent+Job+to+a+child+Job) result, which may be of help to you. You basically just need to pass the variable from job 1 to job 2, which appears to be possible (keeping in mind I've never even heard of Talend)